# Detect cursor movement in GTK text buffer

Tags: c, gtk

I am working on a GTK+ editor in C. I have added a feature of displaying the current line number and column number of the cursor position in the textview. Its working well. But the drawback is when I attempt to move the cursor with the arrow keys the line number and column number do not get updated. Below is my code for updating the line number and column number

```
    update_statusbar(GtkTextBuffer *buffer,GtkStatusbar  *statusbar)
{
  gchar *msg;
  gint row, col;
  GtkTextIter iter;

  gtk_statusbar_pop(statusbar, 0); 
  g_print("c");
  gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark(buffer,
      &iter, gtk_text_buffer_get_insert(buffer));

  row = gtk_text_iter_get_line(&iter);
  col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset(&iter);

  msg = g_strdup_printf("Col %d Ln %d", col+1, row+1);

  gtk_statusbar_push(statusbar, 0, msg);

  g_free(msg);
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
.
.
.
.
.
.
  g_signal_connect(buffer, "changed", G_CALLBACK(update_statusbar), statusbar);
  update_statusbar(buffer, GTK_STATUSBAR (statusbar));

}
```

I guess the problem is with "changed" signal. Since the cursor is moved with arrow keys, buffer doesn't get changed. So can anyone suggest me a better way to solve the problem .

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: This has the feeling of "Here's my code, fix it for me." What have you tried? How do you know the problem is in this block of code?

Comment: This code works pretty good when the buffer is changed. My line number and column number in the status bar gets changed. I've provided my code just as a reference to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TextBuffer "cursor-position" property](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer--cursor-position) has the buffer offset of the insertion mark (aka cursor).  The signal corresponding to this property changing is named "notify::cursor-position", and is a notify signal as [defined in gobject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#GObject-notify).

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of text buffer signals [here](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.22/class-gtktextbuffer.html) and a list of general widget signals [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html).

The latter link has a signal called [`key-release-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-release-event) which you will probably find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the probably the best way to do this job. Although the move_cursor signal on GtKTextView works well for key press. It does not respond to mouse click based cursor position change. Notify signal on GtKTextView works for mouse click but causes thread conflict while trying to update the buffer's insert position. So the best thing is to directly associate the signal "notify::cursor-position" to the buffer behind GtKTextView. No need to associate signal to GtKTextView.